# Can't find an element on a frame Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, recaptcha, frame, nosuchelementexception

I'm trying to make a bot that logs into my account.

After inserting password and username I make the bot clicking on the "I'm not a robot recaptcha" using this code and it works:

```
def _delay():
      time.sleep(randint(1,3))

frames = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe') 
driver.switch_to_frame(frames[0])    
recaptcha = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="recaptcha-anchor"]/div[1]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",recaptcha)  
_delay()
```

After this it opens up the image recaptcha.

Now, I would like to try using the audio to text method but I can't click on the "audio" button under the images. Here's the code I used :

```
#finding the frame
driver.switch_to_default_content()
element_image = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body')
element = element_image.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')
driver.switch_to_frame(element[0])

_delay()

#clicking on the "audio" button
button = driver.find_element_by_id('recaptcha-audio-button')  #error
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",button)
```

Here is the output : `Exception has occurred: NoSuchElementException

I have no idea on how to click on the "audio" button. This seems correct to me but still doesn't work.
Any tips ?
`

Comment: what is `_delay()` ? Are you trying to insert a wait to allow for the element to load? If so, that's not the right way to use Selenium.

Comment: Yeah sorry I forgot to specify it. _delay() is a function i made that waits between 1 to 3 seconds. Thanks for the reply anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this is happening because your `delay()` function is finishing before the page element is visible. You could try increasing the length of time it pauses to verify, but the better approach is to refactor this to use Selenium `WebDriverWait` objects.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotVisibleException, ElementNotSelectableException

driver = webdriver.Firefox() # or chrome...
fluent_wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10, poll_frequency=1, 
                            ignored_exceptions=[ElementNotVisibleException, 
                                                ElementNotSelectableException])
elem = fluent_wait.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "recaptcha-audio-button")))
if elem:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",button)
else:
    print("couldn't find button")
```

Comment: Hey thank you ! I tried your solution but it doesn't work. It gives me TimeoutException and doesn't reply with "couldn't find button". I could have used your solution wrong though,